# What is a group/herd of rhinos called in French?

Tags: traduction

In English, a group of rhinos is called a "crash". What would it be called in French? I'm having trouble finding this in Google.

Comment: They are called *extrêmement dangereux*. :)

Comment: « Ces animaux évitent les hommes et chargent lorsqu'ils se sentent menacés, essentiellement pour protéger les jeunes rhinocéros. Très rares, ces attaques peuvent parfois occasionner de graves blessures [...] » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhinoc%C3%A9ros#Biologie_et_comportement)). Certainly less so than those they seek to avoid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rhinos are pretty solitary animals and they rarely live in groups. However there are two words that can be used in French for a group of rhinos (apart from *troupeau* which is a the general term for a "herd" and not particular to the species).

***Clan*** is mostly used by specialists. This name has obviously been given in accordance to their way of life.

> Le rhinocéros noir est un animal au mode de vie plutôt solitaire, surtout les mâles adultes. Les femelles et les jeunes sont plus sociables. Dans certaines régions toutefois, les rhinocéros noirs sont organisés en clans. Ceux-ci regroupent quelques dizaines d'individus, mâles et femelles, qui exploitent le même point d'eau. ([Encyclopédie Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/encyclopedie/vie-sauvage/rhinoc%C3%A9ros/178163))

> Un clan de rhinocéros est presque toujours composé d'un mâle adulte dominant, de plusieurs femelles et leurs petits. La territorialité des rhinocéros est ... ([L'art des cavernes en action: Tome 1 : les animaux modèles. Aspect, locomotion, comportement](https://books.google.fr/books?id=6H4pEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA166&lpg=PA166&dq=%22clan%20de%20rhinoc%C3%A9ros%22&source=bl&ots=KMPDrdy3DE&sig=ACfU3U28E0bEIweuadM4BugUnR4F9B3hZw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv3Yjg1d_yAhVMxYUKHY8ZDIkQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22clan%20de%20rhinoc%C3%A9ros%22&f=false), Marc Azema)

> **Baptisée « Opération Crash », le terme anglais pour désigner un clan de rhinocéros**<sup>1</sup>, l'opération secrète multinationale a débuté il y a sept ans, lorsque les autorités responsables de l'application de la loi relative aux espèces sauvages ont constaté une hausse du nombre de rhinocéros victimes du braconnage. ([National Geographic](https://www.nationalgeographic.fr/animaux/2018/08/un-new-yorkais-condamne-9-mois-de-prison-pour-trafic-illegal-despeces-sauvages), 2018).

***Fracas*** can also be found to call a group of rhinos. I do not think it is a scientific word, as the word "crash" in English ["was most likely inspired by the rhino’s tendency to charge at anything unfamiliar](https://www.jellyfish.com/en-gb/training/blog/collective-nouns)", the French word must have been inspired by the noise made by the rhinos charging.

> Bien qu'il puisse être facile de penser à tous les animaux en termes de troupeaux et de meutes, il est tellement plus amusant d'apprendre les vrais noms de groupe de certains de vos animaux préférés.[...]  un fracas de rhinocéros... ». ([106 animaux avec des noms de groupe inhabituels](https://www.greelane.com/fr/science-technologie-math%C3%A9matiques/science/animals-with-unusual-group-names-1140747/))

> Je peux dire que la concision est en jeu lorsque j’entends des noms de groupes d’animaux comme « une finesse de singes », « un entêtement de buffles », « une caravane de chameaux », « une tour de girafes », « un tonnerre d’hippopotames », « un picotement de porcs-épics », « un fracas de rhinocéros » et « une ruée d’écureuils ». (Un article d'opinion sur [Hémicycles d'Afrique](https://hemicyclesdafrique.com/opinion-le-parlement-des-hiboux/))

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> My emphasis.</sup>

Comment: Comme terme générique mois "paisible" que "**troupeau** de rhinocéros", j'ajouterais "une **horde** de rhinocéros".

Comment: On ne dit pas « un fracas de rhinocéros » en français ([en tout cas on ne l'écrit pas dans des livres](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fracas+de+rhinoc%C3%A9ros%22)). Déjà qu'en anglais beaucoup de ces noms de groupes sont inventés, alors en français qui n'a pas les quelques noms spécifiques qui sont effectivement attestés en anglais, c'est de la pure frime.

Comment: Genève [aide](http://institutions.ville-geneve.ch/fr/bm/interroge/archives-questions-reponses/detail/question/je-cherche-une-liste-repertoriant-les-termes-utilises-pour-designer-les-differents-groupes-dani/) ; [207 ici](https://ast-arci.ch/arci/archives/category/publications) pour l'article manquant. Des trucs bizarres sur le Web donnent l'impression d'équivalents, je pense que certains sites recensent des traductions mot à mot de termes anglais, comme [ceci](https://indefina.fr/noms-collectifs-pour-les-groupes-danimaux/#). On a une _amorce des_ rhinocéros, ça vient de _primer_ possiblement ??

Answer (score 5):

The word for elephants is "troupeau" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=troupeau+d%27%C3%A9l%C3%A9phants&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctroupeau%20d%27%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phants%3B%2Cc0)), and it is also used rhinoceroses ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=troupeau+de+rhinoc%C3%A9ros&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctroupeau%20de%20rhinoc%C3%A9ros%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctroupeau%20de%20rhinoc%C3%A9ros%3B%2Cc0)). For those animals the word "*groupe*" is also used, but less often. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=groupe+de+rhinoc%C3%A9ros&share=&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3)).

[image]

[image]

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Un_%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant_dans_ma_cuisine/unihDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22groupe+de+rhinoc%C3%A9ros%22&pg=PT63&printsec=frontcover)) Tu ne devineras jamais comment s'appelle un groupe de rhinocéros, me dit-il. Je secouais la tête. — Un « crash » de rhinocéros, dit-il en souriant.